# Adding an eventListener to each checkbox

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a clean and concise way to add event listeners to each of my checkboxes without having to repeat my Javascript code, I'm still wet behind the ears when it comes to JS, so any assistance would be  greatly appreciated.

**Here's what I have so far**

```js
   function exFunction() {};

// on-click
var x = document.getElementById("checkboxopt");
x.addEventListener("click", function(){
    console.log("Opt");
  });

var y = document.getElementById("checkboxopt1");
y.addEventListener("click", function(){
    console.log("Opt 1");
  });
var z = document.getElementById("checkboxopt2");
z.addEventListener("click", function(){
    console.log("Opt 2");
  });
```

```html
<div id=""><input name="checkboxopt" id="checkboxopt" value="true" type="checkbox"><br/></div>
<div id=""><input name="checkboxopt" id="checkboxopt1" value="true" type="checkbox"><br/></div>
<div id=""><input name="checkboxopt" id="checkboxopt2" value="true" type="checkbox"><br/></div>
```

Comment: look up `event delegation` in javascript, in this case you have to add only one listener

Comment: This belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com since it's looking to improve working code.

Comment: @pwolaq Yet another fancy term to learn! I just love JS. :)

Comment: you want attach same function every time?

Comment: @Ivan yeah same function.

Comment: @squint, thanks for the heads up, never even knew this existed.

Comment: use class instead of different id's

Comment: @Ivan, due to the nature of the project, I cannot edit the Raw HTML / CSS files. Gotta go with what I got or edit it within the JS file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either select all and loop over the collection and add the events to each element in the collection.

```js
var cbs = document.querySelectorAll('[type="checkbox"]');
[].forEach.call(cbs, function (cb) {
    cb.addEventListener("click", function(){
        console.log(this.id);
    });
});
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="">
    <input name="checkboxopt" id="checkboxopt" value="true" type="checkbox">
  </div>
  <div id="">
    <input name="checkboxopt" id="checkboxopt1" value="true" type="checkbox">
  </div>
  <div id="">
    <input name="checkboxopt" id="checkboxopt2" value="true" type="checkbox">
  </div>
</div>
```

or event delegation and use the event object to figure out what element was clicked.

```js
var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrap');
wrapper.addEventListener("click", function (evt) {
    var elem = evt.target;
    if (elem.name==="checkboxopt") {
        console.log(elem.id);
    }
});
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="">
    <input name="checkboxopt" id="checkboxopt" value="true" type="checkbox">
  </div>
  <div id="">
    <input name="checkboxopt" id="checkboxopt1" value="true" type="checkbox">
  </div>
  <div id="">
    <input name="checkboxopt" id="checkboxopt2" value="true" type="checkbox">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your event object approach sounds highly appealing, I'll do some testing and tinkering. Thanks for your example and thoughts on this.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can iterate in each checkbox:

```
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
for(var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++){
     var checkbox = checkboxes[i];
     checkbox.addEventListener('click', function(){
         console.log(this);
     });
}
```

Hope that helps.

Cheers

Comment: creating and using the variable in the loop like this will most likely cause unexpected behaviour since only the last element will get the eventbinding, due to variable hoisting.

Comment: @ErikSvedin: That's only if that variable is used inside the event handler. His answer doesn't do that, since it uses `this` to log the element. Though this doesn't give the output shown in the question, neither do any of the others. The variable here is mostly just unnecessary.

Comment: Variable checkbox is fine, and is just an object pointer, and yes is unecessary but much more readable for who read it, and doesn't affect performance since is just a pointer to another object, garbage collector would take care of it. Plus, it has been asked to a way to don't repeat code, this does not repeat code as in the example in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `for` loop and create function outside of loop.

```js
var c = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
for (let i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
  clickFunction(i)
}

function clickFunction(num) {
  c[num].addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log('Opt ' + (num + 1));
  })
}
```

```html
<div id=""><input name="checkboxopt" id="checkboxopt" value="true" type="checkbox"><br/></div>
<div id=""><input name="checkboxopt" id="checkboxopt1" value="true" type="checkbox"><br/></div>
<div id=""><input name="checkboxopt" id="checkboxopt2" value="true" type="checkbox"><br/></div>
```

Or with ES6 you can use `let` instead of `var` which have block scope so in each iteration of loop new `i` will be created.

```js
var c = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
for (let i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
  c[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log('Opt ' + (i + 1));
  })
}
```

```html
<div id=""><input name="checkboxopt" id="checkboxopt" value="true" type="checkbox"><br/></div>
<div id=""><input name="checkboxopt" id="checkboxopt1" value="true" type="checkbox"><br/></div>
<div id=""><input name="checkboxopt" id="checkboxopt2" value="true" type="checkbox"><br/></div>
```